# UICollectionView Swipe to delete iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have already referred this link [Swipe to delete on CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803591/swipe-to-delete-on-collectionview)

it is written in swift I have done my project in objective c so I would like to continue in objective c

I have a UICollectionView which has some labels.My aim is to present two buttons a delete and edit button when I swipe the UICollectionView cell I am giving data to collection view dynamically

Below is my code-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
//int i=[self.name count];
return 5;

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
AllProCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.buttondel.hidden=YES;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
cell.pcatelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
return cell;
}

-(void) handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

    NSLog(@"swipped");
}
```

I have intercepted the swipe gesture now how to I move the cell and present two buttons for editing and deleting purposes???

I am getting "swipped" in my log  when I swipe my collection view cell

Comment: Hi Akshay, This is not the correct way todo with collection. If you tried definitely you will achieve your requirements, but code will be complicated.

Comment: so what is the correct way??@PhaniRaghu

Comment: You have to use table view for your requirement.

Comment: I am trying your requirement. I reach it with collectionview. I will tell you.

Comment: Actually the problem is I am having 5-6 labels and these values are big so I tot of collection view instead of tableview

Comment: Provide an image of your screen(dummy).

Comment: https://ibb.co/nJpAba

Comment: I have in some fields address to I dont think that ll fit in tableview so I chose collection view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe to delete on CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803591/swipe-to-delete-on-collectionview)

Comment: I am unable to see your image. But data is not a matter to display in table view. If adjusting height is a problem then we can self sizing cells.

Comment: @phi I already referred that question it is in swift please read my question correctly I am here for objective c

Comment: @PhaniRaghu so how to implement any idea??? I will check with height

Comment: I am unable to see your image. If I seen your image I will give you an idea. Post image  in this.

Comment: did u check that link it works for me @PhaniRaghu

Comment: Yup. I checked it. Its a server problem. Problem is from my side.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/286sgad/9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150910/discussion-between-phaniraghu-and-akshay).

Comment: You should use a table view for that

Comment: @PatrickBodet I am not able to fill the datas in tableview i.e for example I have total of 5 labels and one of them is address it is too big

Comment: is there no other way?@PatrickBodet

Comment: @PatrickBodet this guy has achieved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803591/swipe-to-delete-on-collectionview?noredirect=1&lq=1 but swift:(

Comment: You can have some big cells, what is the problem? When I have a look to your image, I think it is possible to fit all these informations in a table view cell!